# Have element hidden on default depending on dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, hide, element

I have a form element, that is hidden or show depending on a dropdown element in my form. I've been able to change the visibility when the dropdown changes.

Here's my code right now:

```
$("select[name=post_category]").change(function(){
var id = $("select[name=post_category]").val();
if(id != 3){
    $("dt#post_url-label").hide();
    $("dd#post_url-element").hide();
}
else{
    $("dt#post_url-label").show();
    $("dd#post_url-element").show();
}
});
```

What I want is the fields to be hidden, unless the page loads with id=3 (so i can't just hide them with CSS), in that case the field has to be visible from the start. Right now, the field is always visible on pageload.

Any suggestions how I should go about this?

Comment: Can't you just add style="display:none;" to the html with php?

Comment: No, because I want the field to be visible when the id=3. I have to check that somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select[name="post_category"]').change(function() {
    $('dt#post_url-label, dd#post_url-element').toggle( +this.value === 3 );
}).change();
```

The idea is to trigger the change event immediately. You should be able to achieve that by using either `triggerHandler('change')` or just `change()`.

**Live demo 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/XE78E/
**Live demo 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/XE78E/1/

The 2. demo shows that the element is visible if the 3-rd option is preselected.

Comment: None of those is working, element always stays hidden. Much cleaner code though, thanks for that!

Comment: @Sled I've updated my code. I've added the `+` prefix operator in front of `this.value` in order to cast the value to Number. It should work now. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

so why dont u check on page load if the id = 3 or not and use same logic to hide or show the element.

Comment: that's what I'm doing in the else block, and it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

That code is javascript, right?
Call $("select[name=post_category]").change() on page load.

```
window.onload = function() { $("select[name=post_category]").change() }
```

or add it to your existing onload function.

Comment: this isn't working, i'm placing it inside $(document).ready(), right?

Comment: @Slet Did you test the call to $("dt#post_url-label").hide(); without any ifs?